# Drupal - System for testing students

Tags: drupal, testing

I want to create a system for testing students on Drupal. 
For example we have some course called “Java”. And after 1-3 months we need to test student about their knowledges – with results base, marks, etc.
Maybe you can help me? What modules I can use for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would definitely want to have a look at the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module. Each test can then be an node, which your students can fill in if they have an account on the site.